# Windows 10 Start Menu Not Closing When Starting Programs

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu

A strange problem with my start menu has appeared recently. Whenever I click on a tile or search result to start a program, the start menu stays open after I have clicked on it, rather than closing like it should. The start menu does eventually load the program that I selected, and the program stays open, but the start menu isn't acting as it should. Whilst the start menu remains open I can also choose other applications and they open so I doubt it's a refresh issue.

I have checked disk performance, and it is fine (I am running a Samsung 850 Pro SSD and I did benchmarks/updated firmware). It is a small nusiance, but it is driving me insane.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it eventually opens the program that I selected, but the start menu stays open rather than closing after I select something like it ought to. It makes me think that the process hasn't started, and I go to the processes list to check.

Comment: But, after you open the program it stays open. Can you open another programme at that point or does it not respond

Comment: It stays open, and I can open another program at that point, yes. The problem is just that the start menu is acting sluggish. The start menu will stay open until that program loads a new window.

Comment: Please edit your question and include this as it is important . Sadly, my ideas are normal. Update all drivers from manufacturer website, not MS site. Try rebuilding the index.

Comment: You got it Dave!

Comment: Are all your drivers up to date? Did you rebuild the index

Comment: Updated the chipset driver, and that seems to have helped significantly. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up finding my answer to the problem. It turns out that my SSD was failing a month after I got it. Yeah, I got sent a defective one. Samsung is has the drive right now and they are checking up on it. Soooo much fun!

Answer (score 0):

Update your drivers, including chipset and also rebuild the index (there are many tutorials on how to build the windows 10 index if you search)